# Cycle route program in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have created a program in prolog which should give me all possible routes between two stations. In each route each station should only get visited once. My code so far is:

```
% facts

connection(s1,s2).
connection(s1,s4).
connection(s2,s3).
connection(s2,s5).
connection(s3,s4).
connection(s4,s5).
connection(s5,s6).
connection(s6,s1).

% predicates

direction1(X,Y) :- connection(X,Y).
direction2(X,Y) :- connection(Y,X).

route1(X,Y,R):- route1(X,Y,[],R).
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction1(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,L,R) :- \+direction1(X,Y), direction1(X,Z), \+member(Z,L), route1(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route2(X,Y,R):- route2(X,Y,[],R).
route2(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction2(X,Y).
route2(X,Y,L,R) :- \+direction2(X,Y), direction2(X,Z), \+member(Z,L), route2(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route(X,Y,R) :- route1(X,Y,R); route2(X,Y,R).
```

The problem is that prolog doesn't give me all routes, for exampel when I ask for route[s1,s4,R], prolog doesn't give me the route [s1,s2,s3,s4]. I think it is caused by "+direction1(X,Y)" and "+direction2(X,Y)". But I need this to prevent prolog visiting a station multiple times in a route. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimally invasive fix would be to remove the `\+direction1(X,Y)` that you correctly identified as the source of this failure, and to add another `\+ member(X, L)` guard in the definition of `route1/4`.

EDIT: The above does not suffice. Here is a cleaner rewrite of the whole thing, with more readable formatting and variable names:

```
route1(X,Y,R):- route1(X,Y,[X],R).  % note that X is visited immediately
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction1(X,Y).
route1(X, Y, Visited, Route) :-
    direction1(X, Z),
    Z \= Y,
    \+ member(Z, Visited),
    route1(Z, Y, [Z|Visited], Route1),
    Route = [X|Route1].
```

You should then probably unify the two variants of the route predicates: One of them only finds routes that are only along "direction 1" edges and the other only the ones along "direction 2" edges. In general, you will want to be able to traverse any edge in any direction.

Comment: What doesn't give you all the routes, the change I described in the first paragraph or the one in the second? Which routes doesn't it give you?

Comment: For example when I ask for "route(s2,s5,R)" it only gives me "R = [s2,s5]", but there also exists a route like [s2,s3,s4,s5].

Comment: Thanks, do I need to change anything in route2 too?

Comment: As I said, it would be better to unify the two predicates: The only difference is in `direction1` vs. `direction2`. If you define `arc(X, Y) :- connection(X, Y). arc(X, Y) :- connection(X, Y).`, you should be able to just use `arc` instead of `direction1` and completely drop `direction2` and `route2`.